# expected type error when attempting to insert into Cassandra table using a prepared statement with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, cassandra

I have the following cassandra table:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable ( 
             col1 int  
            ,col2 text   
            ,col3 int  
            ,PRIMARY KEY(col1) 
        );
```

and I am using the following python code to read CSV files from an S3 bucket and insert the data they contain into the table:

```
bucket = s3.Bucket(settings.BUCKET)

cluster = Cluster([settings.CASSANDRA_NODE])
session = cluster.connect()
query = """
   INSERT INTO %s.mytable ( col1  
                           ,col2   
                           ,col3  
     VALUES (?, ?, ?)
""" % (settings.KEYSPACE)
prepared = session.prepare(query)

    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')), sep=",", header=None)
        df.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
    
        for row in df.itertuples():
            session.execute_async(prepared, [(getattr(row, 'col1')), getattr(row, 'col2'), getattr(row, 'col3')])
```

When I run the code, I get:

```
TypeError: Received an argument of invalid type for column "col1". Expected: <class 'cassandra.cqltypes.Int32Type'>, Got: <class 'int'>; ('i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647)
```

Firstly, my understanding is that a 32 bit integer in python should map to a 32 bit integer in cassandra, using df.astype to explicitly cast col1 to an int32 makes no difference. I cannot find any fully coded up examples of how to use prepared statements for inserts with pandas dataframes anywhere, either on here or in the datastax python driver documentation. Obviously, there is something I am missing here, can someone please advise as to how I rectify this issue.

Comment: Do you really need to use custom Python code to load data? Why not use the combination of aws-cli + DSBulk (https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html) ?

Comment: Firstly, despite the fact I am using S3, it is S3 on an on-premises S3 compatible storage appliance, therefore I'm not sure that the aws-cli would work in this instances, I believe I would have to make the CSV files available on a local file system for DSBulk to work, I don't beleive that I can load Cassandra using DSBulk straight from S3, finally I'm not sure if I could use DSBulk in a python based data pipeline, making call outs to external executable can be a less than elegant solution.

Comment: DSBulk is heavily optimized for loading of big amounts of data - parallel requests, request throttling (it's easy to get overload error when using async requests), etc. DSBulk understands HTTP protocol, so you can just make files accessible over it

Comment: OK, so it looks like I can I use a URL that points to my CSV files in my bucket, but DSBulk has no API, correct ?

Comment: You can DSBulk as library, but from Java program